# Regex to remove multimedia extensions from filename

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip, file-extension, sanitization

I want strip all multimedia file extensions from a filename using `preg_replace()`.

File extensions to remove:

- .m4a
- .wav
- .ogg
- .flac
- .avi
- .flv
- .mov
- .m3u
- .mid
- .webm
- .mkv
- .asf
- .mpg
- .mpeg
- .mp(INT)
- .mpg(INT)
- .mpeg(INT)
- .aif
- .aiff
- .3gp
- .3gpp
- .wma
- .wmv

My coding attempt:

```
$filename = 'bla.mp3 bla bla.mid.mp3.mp4.mid.mp10.mpeg.mpg.mpg10';
echo preg_replace('/[\.(m4a|wav|ogg|flac|avi|flv|mov|m3u|mid|webm|mkv|asf|wm(a|v)|mp(\d+)|aif(?:f?)|3gp(?:p?))]*$/', '', $filename);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$filename = 'bla.mp3 bla bla.mid.mp3.mp4.mid.mp10.mpeg.mpg.mpg10';
echo preg_replace('/\.(m4a|wav|ogg|flac|avi|flv|mov|wmv|m3u|mid|wma|webm|mkv|asf|mp(\d+)|aif(?:f?)|3gp(?:p?)|mp(eg(\d+)?|g(\d+)?))/g', '', $filename);
```

you can check it out [here](http://refiddle.co/gt9)

---

**Edit**

```
echo preg_replace('/\.(m4a|wav|ogg|flac|avi|flv|mov|wmv|m3u|mid|wma|webm|mkv|asf|mp(\d+)|aif(?:f?)|3gp(?:p?)|mpe?g\d*)/g', '', $filename);
```

you can check it out [here](http://refiddle.co/gtc)

---

**Final Edit**

removed handling `mp(\d+)` and handling `mpe?g\d*`
and used only `mp(e?g)?\d*` to handle both cases and that is the simplest it could get -in my humble opinion-

```
echo preg_replace('/\.(m4a|wav|ogg|flac|avi|flv|mov|wmv|m3u|mid|wma|webm|mkv|asf|aif(?:f?)|3gp(?:p?)|mp(e?g)?\d*)/g', '', $filename);
```

you can check it out [here](http://refiddle.co/gtd)

**author edit**

this is the simplified form of it

```
echo preg_replace('/\.a(if(?:f?)|sf|vi)|fl(ac|v)|m(3u|4a|id|kv|ov|(p(e?g)?\d*))|ogg|‌​w(av|ebm|m(a|v))/g', '', $filename);
```

Comment: yeah, it works better, but is it possible to simplify the pattern for mpeg format?

Comment: maybe mp(?:e|eg?)\d+ ?

Comment: added an edit to the answer simplifying mp3,mp4,mpg,mpe,mpeg,mpg10,mpe3,mpeg2

Comment: edited the answer to exclude mpe4 as you didn't describe you wanted it to be captured

Comment: I simplified the pattern a(sf|vi)|fl(ac|v)|m(3u|4a|id|kv|ov)|ogg|w(av|ebm|m(a|v))

Comment: official version: 

`preg_replace('/\.a(if(?:f?)|sf|vi)|fl(ac|v)|m(3u|4a|id|kv|ov|(p(e?g)?\d*))|ogg|w(av|ebm|m(a|v))/g', '', $filename);`

:)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$filename = 'bla.mp3 bla bla.mid .mp3 .mp4 .mid .mp10 .mpeg .mpg .mpg10';
echo preg_replace('/\.(m4a|wav|ogg|flac|avi|flv|mov|wmv|m3u|mid|wma|webm|mkv|asf|mp\d|aif(?:f?)|3gp(?:p?))*/', '', $filename);
?>
```

Update:

```
echo preg_replace('/\.(mpg10|mpeg|mpg|m4a|wav|ogg|flac|avi|flv|mov|wmv|m3u|mid|wma|webm|mkv|asf|mp\d|aif(?:f?)|3gp(?:p?))*/', '', $filename);
```

Comment: ok but you didn't created pattern for them I just re-used your pattern and corrected it, you can also include them, or see my update

Comment: sorry, my english is not very well and you could not understand me, but very thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the desired pattern logic grouped by leading letter and condensed.

Use the `x` pattern modifier to ignore whitespaces in the pattern -- this allows the runnable pattern to be written over multiple lines for easier human reading.

Pattern: ([Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hq0PDw/1))

```
#
\.
(
  3gpp?
  |a(vi|sf|iff?)
  |fl(ac|v)
  |m(4a|ov|3u|id|kv|p\d+|pg\d*|peg\d*)
  |ogg 
  |w(av|ebm|m[av])
)
#xi
```

The outermost square braces in your attempted pattern made all of the inner characters into members of a "character class" -- there were treated as a list of individual, literal characters.